# Unity3D GUI Controls creates two of themselves

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a code that show users a Yes/No question that they really would like to quit game or not.Here is my code :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class UserPrompt : MonoBehaviour {

public int count = 0;
public bool paused = false;

public static UserPrompt Instance;


// Use this for initialization
void Awake ()
{
    if (Instance == null)   
    {   
        Instance = this;    
    }
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () 
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
    { 
        paused = true;
        count = 1;
    }

    if(paused)
        Time.timeScale = 0;
    else
        Time.timeScale = 1;
}

void OnGUI ()
{
    if(count == 1)
    {
        GUI.Box(new Rect(0,0,Screen.width,Screen.height),"Exit");
        GUI.Label(new Rect(Screen.width*1/4,Screen.height*2/6,Screen.width*2/4,Screen.height*1/6), "Do you really want quit to main menu ?");
        if(GUI.Button(new Rect(Screen.width/4,Screen.height*3/8,Screen.width/2,Screen.height/8),"Yes")) 
            Application.LoadLevel("Menu");

        if(GUI.Button(new Rect(Screen.width/4,Screen.height*4/8,Screen.width/2,Screen.height/8),"Keep Playing"))
        {
            paused = false;
            count = 0;
        }
    }
}
}
```

The problem is that i should click on "Keep Playing" button twice to disappear, it seems that this codes creates twice of each GUI object but i can't see whats wrong.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, what complete overkill.

1. A 'singleton' implementation that doesn't actually persist one active copy of the script in scene
2. Unnecessary attempt at 'singleton' pattern when the script is entirely self-regulating. All methods are called as part of the typical engine updates.
3. Use of 'count == 1' to ensure only one active set of GUI instructions in a script that's supposed to be singleton.

**Quick solution**

The really laziest solution to enforce one active GUI per scene, regardless of how many scripts, is to simply tear out the current *Instance* variable and make *Count* private static instead.

**Robust solution**

You don't need the *Count* property at all.

If you're interested in a more robust singleton MonoBehaviour component, consider something like this:

```
private static UserPrompt _instance;
public static UserPrompt Instance 
{
    get
    {
        if (_instance != null)
            return _instance;

        _instance = (UserPrompt )FindObjectOfType(typeof(UserPrompt));

        if (_instance != null)
            return _instance;

        GameObject newObject = new GameObject();
        _instance = newObject.AddComponent<UserPrompt>();

        newObject.name = "UserPrompt";

        if (_instance == null)
            throw new NullReferenceException("Cannot instance UserPrompt");

        return _instance;
    }
}
```

That works if you plan on calling the script into existence when you reference it, like *UserPrompt.Instance* - it assumes there's one in the scene, else it'll create one for you to reference. However you can still accidentally have multiple UserPrompts in the scene with this, so consider also:

```
private void
    OnEnable()
{
    if (_instance == null || !_instance.enabled)
    {
        _instance = this;
    }
    else
    {
        enabled = false;
    }
}

private void
    OnDisable()
{
    if (this == _instance) _instance = null;
}
```

If a new UserPrompt appears in the scene, it will check that there's no active instance, else disable itself. Disabling is preferential to DestroyImmediate(this), which will probably throw a NullReferenceException in the editor. Ofcourse you can choose to simply catch the Exception.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the script is not used in 2 objects, you could also check this by adding a label that will show, this.parent.name, it will show the GO who use the scripts.